# How to set a different number of threads to a different thread group?

Tags: jmeter, yaml, jmx, taurus

Here is my YAML config

```
execution:
- scenario:
 
    script: test.jmx
  concurrency: 3
  iterations: 1
  ramp-up: 1

reporting:
- module: junit-xml
  filename: taurus-output/TEST-Taurus.xml
```

I have 2 thread groups (A, B as an example) in my JMeter test, and I want to run tests with 10 threads for A and 5 for B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove this `concurrency` line or set it to `15`.

According to [Run Existing JMX File](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File) you need to only provide the pass to [JMeter .jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) and not going to perform any [modifications](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) it will be sufficient.

More information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)